# What berachos should be made when Moshiach comes?

Tags: sources-mekorot, blessing, messiah, messianic-redemption

I supose shehecheyanu or hatov vehameitiv, but I'm not sure about this. Are there something more specific than that? What are the mekorot dealing with berachos to be made when Moshiach comes?

Comment: Why would there be such Mekorot? Why would any Brachot be made? (I know you're probably gunning for RSZA's responsum but that doesn't make this a compelling question.)

Comment: הרואה מלכי ישראל.....

Comment: related: will it be said every year: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/101767/will-the-day-of-the-final-salvation-be-celebrated-every-year-in-the-days-of-the

Comment: http://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=32513

Comment: http://www.haoros.com/Archive/index.asp?kovetz=847&cat=1&haoro=0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R Shlomo Aviner answers your question ([here](http://www.ravaviner.com/2020/01/rav-aviner-to-president-putin-do-not-be.html)) citing R Shlomo Zalman Auerbach (Shut Minchat Shlomo, last responsum in vol. 1) who writes that

> One is obligated to recite four blessings when
> the Messiah arrives:
>
> 1. "Baruch…Chacham Ha-Razim – Blessed are You…Knowers of secrets" which is recited when seeing 600,000 Jews together and certainly at
>    least this many Jews will go out to greet the Messiah.
> 2. "Baruch…She-Chalak Mechochmato Lirei'av - Blessed are You…who has appointed of His knowledge to those who fear him" which is recited
>    when seeing an outstanding Torah scholar and the Messiah will
>    certainly fit this criteria.
> 3. "Baruch…She-Chalak Mikevodo Lirei'av- Blessed are You…who has appointed of His glory to those who fear him" which is recited when
>    seeing a Jewish king.
> 4. "Shechechiyanu" – Blessing Hashem for having arrived at this moment.

Comment: Why not Hatov Vehametiv?

Answer (score 0):

Upon hearing of Moshiach’s arrival:

ברוך אתה יי אלהינו מלך העולם גואל ישראל.

Baruch atah A-donay, Elo-heinu Melech Ha’Olam Goel Yisrael.

ברוך אתה יי אלהינו מלך העולם שהחינו וקימנו והיגיענו לזמן הזה.

Baruch atah A-donay, Elo-heinu Melech Ha’Olam
shehecheeyanu v’kiyimanu vihigiyanu lizman hazeh.

When the dead are revived:

ברוך אתה יי אלהינו מלך העולם מחיה המתים.

Baruch atah A-donay, Elo-heinu Melech Ha’Olam Mechaye Hameisim

When seeing Moshiach (before making the Brocha חכם הרזים):

ברוך אתה יי אלהינו מלך העולם שחלק מכבודו ליראיו.

Baruch atah A-donay, Elo-heinu Melech Ha’Olam Shechalak Mikvodo Lireiav

When seeing six hundred thousand Yidden together in Eretz Yisroel:

ברוך אתה יי אלהינו מלך העולם חכם הרזים.

Baruch atah A-donay, Elo-heinu Melech Ha’Olam Chacham Harazim

מקורות:

שהחיינו – ראה שיחת ליל שמח״ת תשמ״ט. תזו״מ תנש״א הערה 134. [ולהעיר משו״ת לב חיים ב, מב. אבל שם מיירי בברכה על היום, ושמברך בכלל קידוש היום]. ושקו״ט בכ״מ מדוע לא לברך מחי׳ המתים. וראה מסעות ירושלים סדר יום ראשון, ו. הר צבי או״ח קטז. [וכן י״ל טעם מצד הבשורה טובה של ביאת הגאולה, וכמדומה שז״כ כונת השואל בשו״ת מנחת שלמה דלקמן. וכבר העירו שאין מברכין שהחיינו על חבר שלא ראהו מעולם, רק ע״י כתבים. ויש שכתבו ליישב שרק אז אין שמחה כ״כ אם לא ראהו מעולם, אבל בביאת משיח ודאי יהיה שמחה גדולה. והביאו ראיה מהפרמ״ג לענין מי שנולד בן וראהו רק אחר חודש או שנה שיכול לברך שהחיינו או מחיה המתים. וכ״ד אדה״ז בסברה״נ  יב, יב לברך שהחיינו בלידת בתו.

ובשעת תחה״מ – ברוך מחי׳ המתים – ע״פ פרדר״א לא. וראה מח״ב ריט. ולהעיר גם משער הגלגולים הקדמה לח קרוב לסופה מה שסיפר הרח״ו ע״ע. וראה גם אמונת התחי׳ (באדיטשוב, תרנ״ו, בהסכמת הגרי״א והאדר״ת ועוד) ד (כב, א) ע״פ סנהדרין צב, ב במתים שהחי׳ יחזקאל. ושם, שמה״ט יקומו בלבושיהם שיוכלו לברך. וכ״ז, לגבי המתים עצמם. ועוד טעם, מדין מי שלא ראה חבירו יב״ח, כנ״ל.

חכם הרזים בשעת קיבוץ גלויות – ראה טושו״ע או״ח רכד. ובא״ר שם שישלחוש לדעת רבינו מנוח שלרמב״ם מברך רק בא״י. וכ״פ בכה׳״ח טו. וראה שיחת ש״פ וארא תשמ״ב – התוועדויות תשמ״ב ב ע׳ 745. שו״ת מנחת שלמה קמא צא, כז בשם הגר״ש הומינר [ולהעיר, שיש מקום לברכה זו גם מצד היותו חכם מופלג – ראה טור שם. אבל ראה בב״י שם בדעת הרמב״ם. ובב״ח שם שלהלכה סב״ל. וראה גם תורת משה להחת״ס פ׳ פינחס,שלא הביאוהו הפוסקים לפי שהוא שלא כדין, עיי״ש. וצע״ק בסברתו ממלחמות ברכות נח, ב, והובא בהקדמת התניא. אבל ראה באו״א זכרון למשה ע׳ פא  -בשמו. ובאו״א – שו״ת דברי ישראל מז. ועוד אופן – ויגד יעקב רשמי רשותא ח. וראה שו״ת יחו״ד ד, טז. ואכ״מ]. וכמובן, בתנאי שיש ס״ר כאחד. (ולהעיר ממאירי ברכות שם בשם י״א בנוגע לאוכלוסא חשובה. אבל למסקנא לא הכריע כן. וגם לא הובא בפוסקים). וגם צ״ל באופן שרואה אותם כאחד – ראה בניהו ברכות נח, א. חוט שני ברכות ע׳ קפט. מפי האיש ע׳ רעט. וראה סברי מרנן ע׳ שסד. תחומין לד ע׳ 455.

בנוגע לברכת שחלק מחכמתו ושחלק מכבודו – ראה מנחת שלמה שם. ונסתפק שם אם לכלול בברכה אחת. ודעת המנחת שלמה בעצמו שלא לכלול. וראה גם מכתבי תורה גור עז. תורת חיים רכד, ט. וכ״ה ע״פ תשובה מאהבה ב, רלז. ובמק״א הארכנו בכללות הענין לכלול ב׳ ברכות. ונראה עיקר כדעת הסוברים שאין לכלול. וברכת חכמתו קודמת לברכת כבודו.

אלא שמטעם אחר יש לפקפק בכ״ז, ראה בשו״ת פעולת צדיק ב, רמו שבאם בירך כבר ברכת חכם הרזים אינו מברך שחלק. ולאידך, ראה דברים אחדים להחיד״א דרוש יג – סב, ב. ולמעשה, סב״ל. ולהעיר מיומן ד׳ שבט תש״י.

ולהעיר שבלב חיים שם כתב שמברך גואל ישראל על הגאולה. והיינו לא על גוף ביאת והתגלות משיח. וצ״ע מקורו.

ברכת הטוב והמטיב – אין לברך, ראה מורי׳ ז, ו-ז. ולהעיר ממג״א רכה, א. פמ״ג שם. לוח ברה״נ יא, כב. כג.

וראה בכהנ״ל בארוכה שו״ת עטרת פז או״ח א, טו בהערות. ויזרח אור א. שיח הנחמה ע׳ קטו. ימוה״מ בהלכה א, ח ואילך.

מאת הרב יוסף ישעיה ברוין רבה של שכונת קראון הייטס

[From AskTheRav.com](https://asktherav.com)

Answer (score -4):

Unlike the popular myth (endorsed by Avrum Fried in his songs) that the Moshiach will come (unclear where from) riding a donkey and everybody will mediately recognize him as such and all of sudden the days of Moshiach will begin, according to Rambam's Melachim, **the coming of the Mochiach is a long process** spanning probably tens of years.

He emerges slowly, proving himself as the national leader, overcoming the enemies, bringing the Jews together in the Promised Land and finally successfully building the Temple (Rambam Melachim 11,4).

> "אם עשה והצליח ובנה מקדש במקומו וקבץ נדחי ישראל הרי זה משיח בודאי "
>
> If he succeeds in the above, builds the Temple in its place, and gathers the dispersed of Israel, he is definitely the Mashiach.

I can't figure from that Rambam when exactly he gets crowned - when he's proven as King David's descendant and is commonly accepted as a king or after he fulfills all the prophecies and builds the Temple.

The Nafka Minah is what blessing we say and when. Although we do have a blessing for seeing a Jewish king and we do say some kind of praises after major salvation (Shirat Hayam after the Exodus or Meggilat Ester after Purim events) I don't recall a clear Halocho on when and what Brocho is said (like Hameitiv or SheYihyanu).

Comment: It comes from Zechariah 9:9. גִּילִ֨י מְאֹ֜ד בַּת־צִיּ֗וֹן הָרִ֙יעִי֙ בַּ֣ת יְרוּשָׁלַ֔‍ִם הִנֵּ֤ה מַלְכֵּךְ֙ יָ֣בוֹא לָ֔ךְ צַדִּ֥יק וְנוֹשָׁ֖ע ה֑וּא עָנִי֙ וְרֹכֵ֣ב עַל־חֲמ֔וֹר וְעַל־עַ֖יִר בֶּן־אֲתֹנֽוֹת׃

Comment: -1 Even so, once the process is complete, are there any Berachos that one must make?

Comment: @DonielF My last paragraph - we didn't see a Brocho in the previous events so we don't have a Halocho onsaying a Brocho in such situations.

Comment: I don’t follow. Why don’t we say a Bracha once the whole process is complete?

Comment: @DonielF THat's why I asked the other question - to say a Brocho we need to set a day/date for it I think.

Comment: @ba Yes I know, it does not "come from", it is *possibly interpreted* in that way, while many if not most interpret it metaphorically.

Comment: I was responding to "unclear where from" because I understood it to mean that it's unclear where the popular myth comes from. Maybe you meant it's unclear where the Messiah is coming from on his donkey? Anyway, I'm not initiated into the metaphorical interpretations, but surely the plain meaning of the verse shouldn't be dismissed as a "popular myth"

Comment: @ba Yes, I meant where does he start his journey? At what point of it people realize he's the one? THat's unclear to me.

Comment: @AlBerko I think it’s a pretty good date to set as when Mashiach comes, he leads the Jews to freedom from our oppressors, and we built the Beis HaMikdash. I think the day that’s completed is as good a date as any.