# Will the day of the final salvation be celebrated every year in the days of the Moshiach?

Tags: calendar, messiah, ymoth-hamoshiach

Following "*[what-berachos-should-be-made-when-moshiach-comes](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/101757/what-berachos-should-be-made-when-moshiach-comes)*", I wondered, for all the great events that G-d did to us we set (in the Torah or Rabbinically) a yearly festive - celebrating the date - Pesach, Purim Chanukkah.

We hold that all those festivals will be canceled in the days of the Moshiach (besides Purim, not clear when and how). So when the Moshiach comes and fights and wins and gathers all the Jews and builds the Temple B"H, will that day (some day, any day) be set as a yearly celebration from that point on or we will have no memory of that day and the great final salvation to celebrate?

Comment: לָכֵן הִנֵּה-יָמִים בָּאִים, נְאֻם-יְהוָה; וְלֹא-יֵאָמֵר עוֹד חַי-יְהוָה, אֲשֶׁר הֶעֱלָה אֶת-בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל מֵאֶרֶץ מִצְרָיִם. כִּי אִם-חַי-יְהוָה, אֲשֶׁר הֶעֱלָה אֶת-בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל מֵאֶרֶץ צָפוֹן, וּמִכֹּל הָאֲרָצוֹת, אֲשֶׁר הִדִּיחָם שָׁמָּה; וַהֲשִׁבֹתִים, עַל-אַדְמָתָם, אֲשֶׁר נָתַתִּי, לַאֲבוֹתָם.

Comment: @DoubleAA Is it a Yes?